# Link solidity source code to deployed contract in forked network

Tags: debugging, ethereum, solidity, hardhat

I am debugging my smart contract using hardhat and local forked mainnet. My contract calls an underlying smart contract which is not deployed by me. When the underlying smart contract fails and throws an exception, the stacktrace only shows `<UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0x contract address)`. I have the source code of the underlying contract and I would like to link it to the deployed binaries so that I know where exactly the exception is thrown. Is there a way to achieve this in hardhat?

Hardhat is able to link my own contract's source code and provde clear stacktrace, so I assume there might be a way. But I did not find any clues in hardhat's docs.

Comment: Take the parameter in to the constructor, and when you test inject a mock